# From String to 2D Char Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I want to convert String puzzle to a 2D Char Array, like a wordpuzzle. This is a part of the testclass:

```
public class WordPuzzleTest {

WordPuzzle myPuzzle = null;

/**
 * This function will initialize the myPuzzle variable before you start a new test method
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Before
public void setUp() {
    try {
        this.myPuzzle = new WordPuzzle("VNYBKGSRORANGEETRNXWPLAEALKAPMHNWMRPOCAXBGATNOMEL", 7);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            System.out.println("An exception has occured");
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

}

/**
 * Test the constructor of the {@link WordPuzzle} class
 */
@Test
public void testWordPuzzle() {
        assertNotNull("The object failed to initialize", this.myPuzzle);
        char[][] expectedArray = {{'V','N','Y','B','K','G','S'},
                                 {'R','O','R','A','N','G','E'},
                                 {'E','T','R','N','X','W','P'},
                                 {'L','A','E','A','L','K','A'},
                                 {'P','M','H','N','W','M','R'},
                                 {'P','O','C','A','X','B','G'},
                                 {'A','T','N','O','M','E','L'}};
        assertArrayEquals(expectedArray, this.myPuzzle.getLetterArray());
}
```

The following is the code I wrote to do this, but I get this error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

I'm not sure why this wouldn't work, but chances are I made a stupid mistake. Anyone any idea?

```
public class WordPuzzle {

    private String puzzle;
    private int numRows;
    private char [][] puzzleArray = new char[numRows][numRows];

    public WordPuzzle(String puzzle, int numRows) {
        super();
        this.puzzle = puzzle;
        this.numRows = numRows;

        char[] puzzleChar;
        puzzleChar=puzzle.toCharArray();

        int index=0;
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        while (i<numRows) {
            while (j<numRows) {
                puzzleArray[i][j] = puzzleChar[index];
                j++;
                index++;
            }
            i++;
            j=0;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Can I suggest writing your test with a smaller input - say, 2x2 or 3x3. It's much easier to make sense of than this enormous blob of "random" letters.

Comment: The test wasn't written by me, it was given. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initializer for `puzzleArray`:

```
private char [][] puzzleArray = new char[numRows][numRows];
```

is invoked before the constructor, when `numRows` is zero, so `puzzleArray.length == 0`.

Just move `puzzleArray = new char[numRows][numRows];` to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int numRows;
private char [][] puzzleArray = new char[numRows][numRows];
```

Might be the cause of this.
The first line inits an int, but does not define a value, so the value becomes 0.
The second line creates an array, with size numRows x numRows, so 0 x 0.
I guess that was not what you intended.